# Irrelevent topic comes out using BERTopic

Tags: bert-language-model

I'm currently trying to learn how to use BERTopic and new to python and was following a guide. The guide was originally for some sort of twitter data, but I figured I would try another set of data.

When I use Abstract of article data, the result shows like this, and I figured one of the perks of using bertopic was not to preprocessing data, and there was no guide to preprocess data.

can someone please share the ideas of why the result is like this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPpBk.png)

I thought it shows certain topic

Answer (score 1):

Due to the TF-IDF like approach (c-TF-IDF) it typically removes stop words automatically if many topics were created. From your image, my guess would be that only two topics were created and that there are quite some stopwords in there. Removing those is quite straightforward and is not really a preprocessing approach as it removes the stop words **after** creating the clusters of semantically similar documents. We only have to do one of the following:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer_model = CountVectorizer(stop_words="english")
topic_model = BERTopic(vectorizer_model=vectorizer_model)
```

or

```py
from bertopic import BERTopic
from bertopic.vectorizers import ClassTfidfTransformer

ctfidf_model = ClassTfidfTransformer(reduce_frequent_words=True)
topic_model = BERTopic(ctfidf_model=ctfidf_model )
```

Answer (score 0):

as it is seen in the image, there exist English stopwords (assuming your text is in English), You can try to remove them and then retrain your model using the following:

```
#remove english stop words
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords = stopwords.words('english') 

#Use CountVectorizer to remove stopwords
vectorizer_model = CountVectorizer(stop_words= stopwords)

#retrain BERTopic
topic_model = BERTopic(embedding_model=your_preffered_embedding,vectorizer_model = vectorizer_model, other_parameters)
```

You can use NLP for preprocessing tasks such as removing punctuation, spaces, urls, numbers, lowercase, tokenization, and so on.

Comment: Please make sure to format your code correctly :)